# Why cannot I see one of my Oracle java jdk in --config java menu?

Tags: java, linux, path, linux-mint

I have recently installed a full Oracle jdk(not just jre) to my laptop, in /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java is its executable, yet when I type

```
 sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

, I cannot see it, I see only Oracle jre. Why and how to fix it?

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java       1091      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java          1081      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java       1091      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 0
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/bin/java to provide /usr/bin/java (java) in auto mode
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install it with `sudo update-alternatives --install` see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/492058) for details.

Comment: thanx. It worked. Btw, does priority mean a priority of version of java when to try files with different java versions, or overall priority for CPU memory or smth like that in some set of applications, not only JDKs ?

Comment: @NiHao92 Priority is used by update-alternatives when you use it in automatic mode. It has nothing to do with anything else.